# Devexpress GridControl Format Conditions

Tags: winforms, gridview, devexpress

Is there anyone who has experience with the Devexpress GridControl.

I have a class which has a List of Objects in it. (This class is binded to the Grid).
This grid has a few columns to display the class.

I want a row to have another color when the list of objects.count is > 1

I've tried to like make an In-Place Editor Repository LookUpEdit item so I have the List of objects to set into a column.

DevExpress Family: Winforms

Comment: What family of devex components you use? ASP.NET, WPF, WinForms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few `methods` that suit your needs. you can use the `Appearance specific events` that are more flexible.

> Check the [Customizing Appearances of Individual Rows and Cells](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument758) on
>   devExpress documentation.

Check this how can you change the appearance conditionally on the basis of some column value:

```
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid;

private void gridView1_RowStyle(object sender, 
DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowStyleEventArgs e) {
   GridView View = sender as GridView;
   if(e.RowHandle >= 0) {
      string category = View.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle, View.Columns["Category"]);
      if(category == "Beverages") {
         e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Salmon;
         e.Appearance.BackColor2 = Color.SeaShell;
      }            
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I looked @ that but I thought it was only for CellStyling. But idd it works on rows 2. I'll try this ;)